# join info from two columns into one

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using a public data set to run some modeling while trying to learn BigQuery SQL. I have a date column but I'm trying to group by day of the year not full date. Date is entered as 2018-2-12 but I'd like it just as 2-12 or 02-12. I have the code to extract the day and month from date but can't find a way to concatenate the two in order for it to be grouped.

```
      SELECT 
        EXTRACT (MONTH FROM sales.date) AS month,
        EXTRACT(DAY FROM sales.date) AS day ,
        ROUND(AVG(sales.bottles_sold/sales.pack), 2) as pack_qty, -- average case or pack
        ROUND(AVG(sales.bottles_sold), 2) AS qty_bottles, -- average total number of bottles
        ROUND(AVG(sales.sale_dollars), 2) as sales_rev, -- average sales rev
        ROUND(AVG((sales.state_bottle_retail - sales.state_bottle_cost) * sales.bottles_sold), 2) AS                          profit, -- avg profit on that day
        ROUND (AVG(sales.volume_sold_liters), 2) as volumeLit, -- average volume in liters
        ROUND (AVG(sales.volume_sold_gallons), 2) as volumeGal -- average volume in gal

      FROM `bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales.sales` AS sales

      GROUP BY 
          month,
          day
       ORDER BY 
        volumeGal DESC;
```

Comment: You would group by the extracted month and date to get this done

Comment: What is the problem with your query?  BigQuery allows column aliases in the `group by`.  Your query works fine when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT 
        EXTRACT (MONTH FROM sales.date) AS month,
        EXTRACT(DAY FROM sales.date) AS day ,
        ROUND(AVG(sales.bottles_sold/sales.pack), 2) as pack_qty, -- average case or pack
        ROUND(AVG(sales.bottles_sold), 2) AS qty_bottles, -- average total number of bottles
        ROUND(AVG(sales.sale_dollars), 2) as sales_rev, -- average sales rev
        ROUND(AVG((sales.state_bottle_retail - sales.state_bottle_cost) * sales.bottles_sold), 2) AS                          profit, -- avg profit on that day
        ROUND (AVG(sales.volume_sold_liters), 2) as volumeLit, -- average volume in liters
        ROUND (AVG(sales.volume_sold_gallons), 2) as volumeGal -- average volume in gal 
   FROM `bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales.sales` AS sales    
      GROUP BY 
          EXTRACT (MONTH FROM sales.date),
          EXTRACT(DAY FROM sales.date) 
       ORDER BY 
        volumeGal DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the CONCAT function inside the SELECT statement. With the following query you will have a single day column with the "day-month" format in the result.

```
   SELECT 
    CONCAT(EXTRACT (DAY FROM sales.date) ,'-', EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sales.date)) AS day ,
    ROUND(AVG(sales.bottles_sold/sales.pack), 2) as pack_qty, -- average case or pack
    ROUND(AVG(sales.bottles_sold), 2) AS qty_bottles, -- average total number of bottles
    ROUND(AVG(sales.sale_dollars), 2) as sales_rev, -- average sales rev
    ROUND(AVG((sales.state_bottle_retail - sales.state_bottle_cost) * sales.bottles_sold), 2) AS                          profit, -- avg profit on that day
    ROUND (AVG(sales.volume_sold_liters), 2) as volumeLit, -- average volume in liters
    ROUND (AVG(sales.volume_sold_gallons), 2) as volumeGal -- average volume in gal

  FROM `bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales.sales` AS sales

  GROUP BY 
      day
   ORDER BY 
    volumeGal DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use + operator for concatenating two strings.

Code:

SELECT
convert(nvarchar,month(sales.date))+'-'+ convert(nvarchar,day(sales.date) ) as date_month ,
ROUND(AVG(sales.bottles_sold/sales.pack), 2) as pack_qty, -- average case or pack
ROUND(AVG(sales.bottles_sold), 2) AS qty_bottles, -- average total number of bottles
ROUND(AVG(sales.sale_dollars), 2) as sales_rev, -- average sales rev
ROUND(AVG((sales.state_bottle_retail - sales.state_bottle_cost) * sales.bottles_sold), 2) AS                          profit, -- avg profit on that day
ROUND (AVG(sales.volume_sold_liters), 2) as volumeLit, -- average volume in liters
ROUND (AVG(sales.volume_sold_gallons), 2) as volumeGal -- average volume in gal

FROM `bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales.sales` AS sales

GROUP BY
date_month
ORDER BY
volumeGal DESC;